# Selecting datepicker element Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, datepicker

I try to select a date form datepicker dropdown menu in Selenium 2 Web Driver. So far I didn't find any solution for the problem.

I am programming in Selenium 2 Java.

The web page I am testing is http://intercity.pl
This is my HTML I am trying to select from:

```
<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu" style="display:  block; left: 1097px; top: 34.5px;">
    <div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block;">
        <table class=" table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;">«</th>
                    <th class="datepicker-switch" colspan="5">Grudzień 2015</th>
                    <th class="next" style="visibility: visible;">»</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="dow">Pn</th>
                    <th class="dow">Wt</th>
                    <th class="dow">Śr</th>
                    <th class="dow">Cz</th>
                    <th class="dow">Pt</th>
                    <th class="dow">So</th>
                    <th class="dow">N</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="old day">30</td>
                    <td class="day">1</td>
                    <td class="day">2</td>
                    <td class="day">3</td>
                    <td class="day">4</td>
                    <td class="day">5</td>
                    <td class="day">6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="datepicker-months" style="display: none;">
        <table class="table-condensed">
            <thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="7">
                        <span class="month">Sty</span>
                        <span class="month">Lu</span>
                        <span class="month">Mar</span>
                        <span class="month">Kw</span>
                        <span class="month">Maj</span>
                        <span class="month">Cze</span>
                        <span class="month">Lip</span>
                        <span class="month">Sie</span>
                        <span class="month">Wrz</span>
                        <span class="month">Pa</span>
                        <span class="month">Lis</span>
                        <span class="month active">Gru</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="datepicker-years" style="display: none;">
        <table class="table-condensed">
            <thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="7">
                        <span class="year old">2009</span>
                        <span class="year">2010</span>
                        <span class="year">2011</span>
                        <span class="year">2012</span>
                        <span class="year">2013</span>
                        <span class="year">2014</span>
                        <span class="year active">2015</span>
                        <span class="year">2016</span>
                        <span class="year">2017</span>
                        <span class="year">2018</span>
                        <span class="year">2019</span>
                        <span class="year new">2020</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the link to web page?

Comment: just do regular clicking on items

Comment: share your code which is not working. will try to correct any issues in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have already found a solution. Instead of clicking on the datepicker I am sending keys to the input field.